# How to switch back from Google+ profile in Blogger

Tags: google-plus, blogger

I connected my Blogger profile with Google Plus, but I don't like it anymore. Can I go back and switch to the old Blogger profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link:
http://www.blogger.com/revert-profile.g

Click this when you are logged into your Google account, and you will land directly on a page where you can switch back to your old Blogger profile.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked For me..
To Check that your profile name is changed first login to your account follow below link 
and check your Blogger Profile Name.

LINK :: https://www.google.com/dashboard        **[1]**

Then Use the link below

LINK :: http://www.blogger.com/revert-profile.g

This will led you to a page where it will ask to "Change the Blogger Profile Display name"
Change the name & Press "Continue To Blogger". The name will be changed. Again 
go to link [1] & check that your Blogger Profile Name is Changed.